# How can I render .mtl for object on iPhone 5 using ThreeJS?

Tags: javascript, ios, three.js, webgl, .obj

I am trying to load .obj files through ThreeJS and have it be cross compatible. I am using the OBJMTLLoader method. The object loads and renders fine for Firefox, Chrome, and IE on Windows; see [falloutfan.com/eyebot](http://falloutfan.com/eyebot) for reference.

On iPhone 5, I am able to see the object, but it is clear that the .mtl did not render. Does iPhone/iOS not support WebGL completely? Are there any workarounds for this? Any help is appreciated.  Below is my code:

```
<html>
<head>

    <script src="threejs/build/three.min.js"></script>
    <script src="threejs/src/loaders/OBJLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="threejs/src/loaders/OBJMTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="threejs/src/loaders/MTLLoader.js"></script>
    <script src="threejs/src/loaders/DDSLoader.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

    <script>

        var scene = new THREE.Scene();
        var camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        clock = new THREE.Clock();

        // ambient
        var ambient = new THREE.AmbientLight(0xeeeeee);
        scene.add(ambient);

        // light
        var light = new THREE.PointLight( 0xffffff, 1, 50 );
        light.position.set(0, 0, 6 ).normalize();
        scene.add( light );

        THREE.Loader.Handlers.add( /\.dds$/i, new THREE.DDSLoader());

        // instantiate a loader
        var loader = new THREE.OBJMTLLoader();

        // load a resource
        loader.load(
            // resource URL
            'eyebot.obj', 'eyebot.mtl',
            // Function when resource is loaded
            function ( object ) {
                object.position.set(0, 0, 0);
                camera.position.set(0, 12, 0);
                camera.lookAt(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
                obj = object;
                scene.add( obj );
            }
        );

        obj = null;
        var render = function ()
        {
            deg_per_sec = 40;
            delta = clock.getDelta();
            requestAnimationFrame( render );
            renderer.render(scene, camera);
            if (obj)
            {
                obj.rotation.x += delta * Math.PI / 180 * deg_per_sec; // Rotates 1 degree per second
                obj.rotation.y += delta * Math.PI / 180 * deg_per_sec * 1.5;
            }

        };

        renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
            antialias: true,
            alpha: true
        });
        renderer.setClearColor( 0x000000, 1);
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        document.body.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        if (window.addEventListener)
            window.addEventListener('load', render, false);
        else if (window.attachEvent)
            window.attachEvent('onload', render);
        else window.onload = render;

    </script>

</body>
```

Comment: you are using compressed textures that your device might not be able to handle.

Comment: On iOS you should also be concerned with resource size limits on any image. See https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/AppleApplications/Reference/SafariWebContent/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone/CreatingContentforSafarioniPhone.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006482-SW15 as well you should check if WebGL is enabled in your iOS safari settings. I do not know what material type the MTLLoader uses, so you may be limited to the canvas renderer without WebGL.

Comment: @Radio, I think you're onto something with resource size. WebGL is able to render a spinning cube with images on each face just fine on vrscrolls.com (each image is 11Kb), but is unable to do so with another another cube on falloutfan.com (each image is 605Kb). I even tried converting the 605Kb image to .jpg, which also failed to render. I may need to learn how to further compress the .dds files and assign the smaller texture to objects rendered by mobile users, unless anyone has other ideas.

Comment: are your textures powers of 2?

Comment: Also, 1024 * 1024 * 32 bits = 4 MB of uncompressed image data. Even if you're sending in 600kb compressed, webGL may be allocating more space beyond the page limit set by Safari. Also, If your image is an off-size I would try a power of two for each dimension, e.g. 1, 2, 4, 8, 16, 32, 64... as I would question mobile webGL's ability to stretch a texture to UV map. I would try to set all of your images to 512px by 512px. You can store several images on the same file if done right, and have very predictable ram allocation. openGL and webGL are similar and there ought to be plenty to google.

Comment: Oh didn't see @gaitat 's answer before I added my comment. Plus one gaitat.

Comment: Power of 2 is something I didn't consider, I'll play around with it and let you know. Thanks for the help, and I'm sure I'm not the only one having this issue.

Comment: I have reduced the size of the .dds file down to a horrendous 5Kb (falloutfan.com/eyebot). Again, it renders fine in browser on Windows, but it still renders black for iPhone. Though I have confirmed through JPGs and PNGs that WebGL does indeed run on iPhone 5. Also, all of the resizes I have done were powers of two.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you look in the JavaScript console for errors? [Remote debugging is your friend](http://developer.telerik.com/featured/a-concise-guide-to-remote-debugging-on-ios-android-and-windows-phone/). Also the iOS Simulator can be similarly debugged

From your comments I'm going to guess if you had looked at the JavaScript console would tell you the error is either you ran out of memory, your images are too big (jpg compression doesn't matter for WebGL, the images will be expanded back to their original uncompressed size).

The most likely error from your comments is you're using .DDS files. .DDS files only work on desktops (usually) as they are generally used for [DXT compressed textures](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc/). No iOS devices support DXT compressed textures. A few Android devices with NVidia GPUs do. For iOS you either need to change those compressed textures to JPG or PNG. Or you need to change them to a compressed format iOS supports like [PVRTC](https://www.khronos.org/registry/webgl/extensions/WEBGL_compressed_texture_pvrtc/).

For example when I run [this three.js sample using DXT compressed texture formats](http://threejs.org/examples/webgl_materials_texture_compressed.html) using the iOS Simulator and I check the JavaScript console in Safari I see

```
[Log] THREE.WebGLRenderer 71 (three.min.js, line 523)
[Warning] THREE.WebGLRenderer: WEBGL_compressed_texture_s3tc extension not supported. (three.min.js, line 2)
[Warning] THREE.WebGLRenderer: EXT_blend_minmax extension not supported. (three.min.js, line 2)
[Warning] THREE.WebGLRenderer: Attempt to load unsupported compressed texture format in .uploadTexture() (three.min.js, line 2, x19)
```

[image]

Comment: do you think it will be possible to convert the DDS files to JPG and have it render correctly?

Comment: It's certainly possible. https://github.com/KhronosGroup/WebGL/blob/master/sdk/tests/conformance/extensions/webgl-compressed-texture-s3tc.html

Comment: Excellent, thank you! I look forward to getting these textures to render on mobile platforms.

Comment: So all I had to do was convert the DDS file to JPG using the tool from www.ddsconverter.com and then point the MTL file to the new JPG file.  Worked like a charm! falloutfan.com/eyebot is lookin good. http://imgur.com/z50s9gW